# Insert a post into the template in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, templates, post, insert, themes

I inserted a post by the ID of it into the a template (footer.php) but I only get the raw text from the post. The html tags and everything else is missing. I tried it with this

```
<?php
$post_id = 32;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
$title = $queried_post->post_title;
echo $title;
echo $queried_post->post_content;
?>
```

and also a with a shortcode and plugin. Same result.
I need the html tags and everything because the site is build with a site builder (elementor) and it has some progressbars inside.

Any Ideas? Is this even possible?

Comment: check this " wp_strip_all_tags " filter are have in your functions.php

Comment: Thanks but nope, isn't use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the filters, here's how your updated code looks:

```
<?php
$post_id = 32;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
$title = $queried_post->post_title;
echo $title;
echo apply_filters('the_content', $queried_post->post_content);
?>
```

Comment: If shortcodes are still missing, try wrapping it with do_shortcode() method as well as apply_filters.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it only loads the slider section and nothing from the content. However in this part of the template there is no slider? So I wonder where it gets it from. I have now to Sliders, the one that should be there and another one there the content from the post id should be.

Comment: Checked an empty site with just header & footer in it. It displays the content from the post 32 correctly but after inserting some content it shows nothing there the post 32 before was. strange